# How to turn back on page tabs in form in Access 2007

Tags: forms, tabs, ms-access-2007

I know I changed some setting (or did something) to make the page tabs in my Access 2007 form disappear, but I can't remember what the setting was. I am not referring to turning on tabs instead of overlapping windows in the Current Database under Access Options. I have that set to show tabs, but it now only shows one tab for my 2-tab form. Previously I could see 2 tabs for this one form. I can still navigate between the tabs in design view by selecting them in the Property sheet.

Any suggestions much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for the style property on the property sheet. You can choose tabs, buttons and none.

[image: tab style]